# Click button to chang color in new activity -android studio

Tags: java, android

I want to change the color of the button.
When you press the button it will show for you to choose red, blue, green and when you choose one color. This color will be shown on the button that was first pressed.

I read problem ----> [Click Button and change background color of another button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457949/click-button-and-change-background-color-of-another-button)
But I not understand.

Comment: Please clarify your question, show what you have tried so far and where / how it failed.

Comment: I see example in http://tutorial.function.in.th/android/example-activity-startactivityforresult

Answer (score 0):

Well for this you can create an alert dialog with buttons 
And in the buttons you have to add.

```
  buttunname.setBackgroundColor(thecolor);
```

And then if the button is clicked the background of the button will be changed after that to the color that you choose